# Use elephas and keras with spark on Centos cluster - theano backend

Tags: apache-spark, centos, pyspark, deep-learning, keras

I could run a code for training and scoring a model using elephas,theano backend on AWS standalone but I am not able to do it on Centos cluster which has spark 1.6 installed. I am getting an error 'Model needs to be compiled before being used' at this line : spark_model.train(rdd, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2, validation_split=0.1)

Code from examples provided in elepha documentation:

```
conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Mnist_Spark_MLP').setMaster('local[8]')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=784))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
sgd = SGD(lr=0.1)
rdd = to_simple_rdd(sc, x_train, y_train)
adagrad = elephas_optimizers.Adagrad()
spark_model = SparkModel(sc,
                         model,
                         optimizer=adagrad,
                         frequency='epoch',
                         mode='asynchronous',
                         num_workers=2,master_optimizer=sgd)
spark_model.train(rdd, nb_epoch=nb_epoch, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=2, validation_split=0.1)
```

What can be the way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you just try to follow the advice of the error message and compile the model?